# The existence of a solution of a quadratic congruence modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be an odd prime number and assume that $p\equiv 7(\textrm{mod}\,8)$. Since $(2\mid p)=1$, it follows that the congruence $2x^2\equiv1(\textrm{mod}\,p)$ is solvable. If $2a^2\equiv1(\textrm{mod}\,p)$, I want to prove that **exactly one** of the following congruences is solvable. 
$$
2x^2-1\equiv a(\textrm{mod}\,p)\qquad ;\qquad
2x^2-1\equiv -a(\textrm{mod}\,p)
$$
How to prove it? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but if you take $p=7$, and $a=2$, then the equations reduce to $x^2$ congruent to $5$, and $y^2$ congruent to $3$ modulo $7$, and no one is solvable.

Comment: you right @Kelenner, Thanks!